# CSS content wider than mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I have any problem of my CSS code inside HTML code. I tried to fixing the problem, but nothing be happen and my content are keep wider than mobile screen.

If I remove the content of my `<article>` and removing `<article>`, this problem may be fixed. I'm confused and what should I do? Please give my code.

**My screenshot:**
[My html results images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0bvd.png)

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="id">
    <head>
        <title>Daftar Kerusakan komputer</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Latar belakang halaman */
            body {
                background-color:whitesmoke;
                list-style-position: unset;
            }

            /* Pengaturan margin dan jenis font */
            *, body {
                margin:0px;
                padding: 0px;
                font-family: Helvetica;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            /* Pengaturan style pada Header */
            header {
                font-family: Arial;
                float: left;
                margin: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: navy;
            }
            
            /* Untuk navbar */
            header li{
                text-align: center;
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 10pt;
                float: left;
                padding: 15px;
                color: white;
            }

            header img {
                float: left;
                margin: 0px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                padding-left: 25px;
                padding-right: 25px;
            }
            
            /* Untuk navigasi */
            header a, header a:link, header a:hover {
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            /* Artikel */
            article {
                text-align: justify;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: white;
                border-radius: 20px;
                margin: 25px;
                line-height: 30px;
                float: left;
                width: 60%;
            }

            /* Untuk membesarkan heading 2 */
            article h1 {
                font-size: 28px;
                line-height: 40px;
            }
            article h2 {
                font-size: 24px;
                line-height: 40px;
            }
            article h3 {
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            article nav {
                border-radius: 20px;
                list-style-position: outside;
                background-color: #efefef;
                padding: 20px;
                overflow: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;
                width: fit-content;
            }
            article ol li, article ul li{
                list-style-position: inside;
            }
            .a ol li {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding-left: 1.3em;
                text-indent: -1.3em;
            }
            .a ol li p,.a ul li {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-indent: 0px;
            }
            hr {
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            figure figcaption {
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
                article {
                    width: 100%;
                    float: left;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="Img/Dragetech Transparent.png" alt="" height="28px" />
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Rakit PC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Beli Laptop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Artikel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Bantuan</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <article>
                <h1>Penyebab dan ciri-ciri hardisk rusak serta cara mengatasinya</h1>
                <hr />
                <figure>
                    <img src="https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/990/869/163/hard-disk-drive-wallpaper-preview.jpg" alt="Gambar hardisk" style="width:100%" />
                    <figcaption>Sumber:</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <nav>
                    <b>Daftar Isi</b>
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="#s_1">Apa itu hardisk?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#s_2">Bagaimana Hardisk Bisa Rusak?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#s_3">Lalu Bagaimana Ciri-ciri Hardisk yang Rusak?</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
                <section id="s_1">
                    <h2>Apa itu hardisk?</h2>
                    <img src="HTML/Img/pngaaa.com-1076148.png" alt="Gambar Hardisk" width="340" />
                    <p>
                        <span title="Hardisk">Hardisk adalah tempat penyimpanan data yang menggunakan piringan yang bermagnet dan juga merupakan alat penyimpanan data secara mekanis.</span> Hardisk sudah ada sejak tahun 1956. Sebelum adanya hardisk, biasanya data akan disimpan dengan Punch tape, Punch card atau Magnetic Drum. Media penyimpanan dulu memiliki kapasitas penyimpanan yang sangat kecil sekali dan itu juga membutuhkan ruangan yang cukup besar. Namun media penyimpanan sekarang sudah memiliki kapasitasnya besar dan ukurannya sudah kecil Namun tak jarang akan luput terjadinya kerusakan hardisk dan biasanya hardisk yang sudah rusak masih dapat diselamatkan dengan membawanya ke jasa data recovery dengan biaya yang sangat mahal sekali.
                    </p>
                </section>
                <br />
                <section id="s_2">
                    <h2>Bagaimana Hardisk bisa rusak?</h2>
                    <p>
                        Seperti yang kita ketahui, semua barang elekronik apapun termasuk komponen dalamnya juga memiliki batas umurnya. Tak hanya itu saja, barang-barang lain yang mengandalkan peralatan secara mekanik juga memiliki batasan umur.
                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Pasalnya, jika terjadi kerusakkan biasanya akan mengeluarkan suara yang tidak biasa atau kita ssebut dengan <i>Click to death</i>. <i>Click to death</i> adalah kondisi dimana hardisk mengalami kegagalan pada <i>head</i> pembaca/menulis data didalamnya. Gejala ini sangat sering terjadi dan jika dibiarkan, maka akan berakibat fatal yang menyebabkan kehilangan data permanen. Ini biasanya terjadi jika hardisk sering terkena guncangan, terjatuh, ataupun terbanting ke permukaan yang keras. Maka hal ini sama sekali tidak bisa dihindari.
                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Dalam beberapa kasus, hardisk yang terjatuh atau sering terguncang akan menggores <i>platter</i> yang digunakan untuk menyimpan data dan mengakibatkan kehilangan data yang tidak bisa direcovery sama sekali. Hal ini disebabkan karena <i>head</i> telah menyentuh ke permukaan si <i>platter</i> itu tersebut.
                    </p>
                </section>
                <section class="a" id="s_3">
                    <h2>Lalu Bagaimana Ciri-ciri Hardisk yang Rusak?</h2>
                    <p>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                Komputer menjadi lebih lambat dari biasanya
                                <br />
                                <img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a29f28dbb75398b3d510c37c520939b7" alt="Komputer lambat" width="300" />
                                <p>
                                    Hardisk yang mempunyai beberapa <i>bad sector</i> akan dipindahkan ke <i>spare area</i> dan akan ditandai sebagai <i>bad sector</i>. Namun bila data kamu berada di area <i>bad sector</i>, maka data anda tidak akan langsung hilang, namun data anda akan dipindahkan ke <i>spare area</i> dan berakibat pada penurunan kinerja pada hardisk kamu, karema hardisk akan bekerja keras untuk membaca/menulis data pada spare area yang mengakibatkan komputer anda menjadi lebih lambat. Namun sebelum menganggap bahwa hardisk anda mengalami kerusakkan, bisa coba dengan mengecek <i>disk</i> anda dengan menggunakan <a href="" target="_blank">HDTune</a>.
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Bila ada <i>sector</i> yang berwarna merah, maka anda siap-siap backup data anda dan menyiapkan uang untuk membeli hardisk baru karena gejala kerusakkan akan bertambah parah dalam beberapa hari kedepan.</li>
                                        <li>Jika semua sektor berwara hijau, maka penyebab komputer lambat bukanlah karena hardisk. Bisa jadi karena <i>overheat</i> pada prosesor, banyak <i>startup program</i>, dan lain sebagainya. Anda bisa melihat artikel berikut ini: <a href="" target="_blank">Penyebab komputer lambat</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <i>Disk usage</i> selalu 100% meskipun tidak ada aplikasi yang berjalan
                                <p>
                                    Mungkin kamu mengira kalau kecepatan menulis/
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </p>
                </section>
            </article>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know about responsive design?

Comment: not sure but `@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {  article { width:auto;   }   }` seems plenty enough

Comment: My CSS are keep wider and @Gamer In The Game solution are not working for me. I'm beginner programmer.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code into:

```
/* Artikel */
        article {
            text-align: justify;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 20px;
            margin-top: 25px;
            line-height: 30px;
            float: left;
            width: 60%;
            margin-left:20%;
        }
```

and:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
            main {
            }
            article {
                width: 100%;
                float: left;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 10%;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It makes position of article are not balanced. right are wider than left.

Comment: I need to have a margin (20px) to making easily and comfortable reading. This grey background need to appear and don't removing any style of this.